# Strange Symbol before Currency in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I am using the `currency` filter in angularjs as shown below:

> `<span ng-if="!Edit">{{ object.property | currency : "£" }} </span>`

However this gives me the output of

> `Â£someNumber` rather than how I want it to be: `£someNumber`

Any suggestions as to why this is/how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have right charset in html head? (`<meta charset="utf-8">`)

Comment: @assistbss yes I am using a shared _Layout.cshtml file with `<meta charset="utf-8" />` in the head

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the html entity instead...

```
<span ng-if="!Edit">{{ object.property | currency : "&pound;" }} </span>
```